# Difference between YCbCr Simple 4:2:2 and Native 4:2:2

Tags: displayport

For YCbCr, what is the difference between Simple 4:2:2 and Native 4:2:2? There is a Display Port Spec that references both of them, but doesn't distinguish between the two.

I understand what YCbCr and 4:x:y are, but I can't find the difference between Native and Simple. All online sources just discuss the differences between 4:4:4, 4:2:2, etc.

Below is an excerpt from the Display Port table:

| Colorimetry Mode |
| --- |
| 4:4:4 or Simple 4:2:2 |
| Native 4:2:2 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple 4:2:2 refers to 4:2:2 with display stream compression (DSC) enabled, which compresses the video data down to the same bitrate as 4:4:4.

You can read about it in more detail on page 123 of the [VESA DSC Standard v1.2a](https://glenwing.github.io/docs/VESA-DSC-1.2a.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Just to clarify: Simple 4:2:2 is a way of implementing 4:2:2 that works at the same bitrate as 4:4:4. This is to reduce system complexity as only the 4:4:4 encoder/decoder is needed (as well as 4:2:2->4:4:4 and 4:4:4->4:2:2 blocks). Essentially as far as the DSC cares, the data is always 4:4:4, but can actually be used for 4:4:4 or 4:2:2.

Comment: @Michael Exactly. I also stumbled across a PhD dissertation - [Design of Display Stream Compression Video Codecs by Shifu Wu](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/9j85h9hn) ([archive.org backup link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220912213929/https://escholarship.org/content/qt9j85h9hn/qt9j85h9hn_noSplash_d6da990480161ea966ceb784e033e1db.pdf?t=r7cdxr)) - that goes deep into the implementation details and will likely make for excellent reference material.